# Why Is It Saying -Alias does not exist for Powershell Set-Mailbox?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am running the below code and I want to try to set Alias to test if I have admin credentials to the exchange server but it is coming back saying the Alias parameter cannot be found.

```
do {
    $success = $False
    $UserCredential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your Exchange admin credentials"

    try
    {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://sign.chlis.domain/powershell -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Kerberos -AllowRedirection
        $output = Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
        Set-Mailbox -Identity tod.wch@gosis.com -Alias "test.test" -WhatIf
        $success = $True
    }
    Catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
        Write-Host "`nERROR: Credentials did not work to connect to Exchage, try again" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "`t$ErrorMessage :: $FailedItem`n" -ForegroundColor Red
        $success = $False
    }
} Until ($success)
```

I put in my non-admin credentials and just get the following

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Alias'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : sign.chlis.domain
```

Comment: This seems an odd way to check whether you have sufficient credentials. Why not just try the operation (i.e., why do you need to check first)?

Comment: Possibly related.  set-mailbox parameters might depend on the type of identity:  https://evotec.xyz/office-365-parameter-cannot-found-matches-parameter-name-userprincipalname-new-mailbox/

Comment: Hey Bill I do not know yet what operation I will perform I am just getting the credentials that I will use during the rest of the script and I want to make sure they are valid administrator credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like the Set-Mailbox is recognizing if I connected to exchange session with admin credentials or not admin credentials and when not logged in as admin it is not giving the Alias parameter because I would not be able to change that without admin credentials.  Once I connect with admin credentials then the Alias parameter works.